# Rust - wrapping trait in an enum for memory layout and simpler generics?

Tags: enums, rust, polymorphism, traits

So I had something like the following in my code:

```rust
// Trait
trait Shape {
    fn area(&self) -> f32;
}

// Rect
struct Rect {
    width: f32,
    height: f32
}
impl Shape for Rect {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        self.width * self.height
    }
}

// Circle
struct Circle {
    radius: f32
}
impl Shape for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        self.radius * self.radius * std::f32::consts::PI
    }
}

// usage
fn use_shapes(shapes: Vec<Box<dyn Shape>>) {
    // ...
}
```

And I really didn't like the `Box<dyn ...>`, both for performance and because it felt gross. My implementations of my trait were few and explicit, so it felt like a good candidate to become an enum.

In the process of converting it to an enum, I stumbled upon the following pattern:

```rust
// Wrapper enum
enum ShapeEnum {
    Rect(Rect),
    Circle(Circle)
}
impl Shape for ShapeEnum {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        match self {
            ShapeEnum::Rect(data) => data.area(),
            ShapeEnum::Circle(data) => data.area(),
        }
    }
}

// new usage
fn use_shapes(shapes: Vec<ShapeEnum>) {
    // ...
}
```

It's pretty neat. It also feels like cheating somehow. It compiles and works as expected, it's just unusual enough that I wanted to see if there are any unexpected drawbacks/costs/quirks that I'm not seeing right now?

I'm also wondering if, because of the deterministic nature of the enum implementation, it would make a good macro? Automatically generating an enum around a trait and a set of its implementors, which itself implements the trait just like a `dyn` version would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to see if there are any unexpected drawbacks/costs/quirks that I'm not seeing right now?

The only real disadvantage I can think of is that you end up centralizing the definition of all those types - making it harder to allow third parties to hook into your code.

You can get around this by adding a dynamic dispatch enum, which means you only get slower behaviour on those externally defined types.

```
// Wrapper enum
enum ShapeEnum {
    Rect(Rect),
    Circle(Circle),
    Dynamic(Box<T: Shape>),
}

impl Shape for ShapeEnum {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        match self {
            ShapeEnum::Rect(data) => data.area(),
            ShapeEnum::Circle(data) => data.area(),
            ShapeEnum::Dynamic::(data) => data.area(),
        }
    }
}
```

> I'm also wondering if, because of the deterministic nature of the enum
>   implementation, it would make a good macro? Automatically generating
>   an enum around a trait and a set of its implementors, which itself
>   implements the trait just like a dyn version would

It looks like the [enum_dispatch](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) crate does almost exactly that.

Disclaimer: I've not used it myself.

Comment: "you end up centralizing the definition of all those types - making it harder to allow third parties to hook into your code" Right, but that's true with any usage of enums. This method not only makes it easier to "switch" to enums, but makes it easier to switch back and forth when evaluating the impact.

The dynamic fallback idea is really neat! Seems like a true best-of-both-worlds option.